# Will Ubuntu automatically adjust to the leap second at the end of the year (2016)?

Tags: time

[The BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-38476906) reports:

> An extra second will be added to the world's clocks on New Year's Eve
>   in order to stay in sync with the Earth's rotation.

Does this mean that I have to do anything so that my Ubuntu machine keeps in time with this or will it automatically adjust itself to not be a second off?

Comment: You  might enjoy this video (which also discuss leap seconds)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Oh, that's Tom Scott!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your Ubuntu machine listens to NTP and synchronizes time with the Internet, the system will automatically adjust itself for the difference in time.

While your computer might not necessarily be aware of the fact that a leap second happened, it will catch and record the event as NTP servers push the change throughout the internet.

If you don't feel like the extra second is being added, you can force an update using the following command:

```
sudo ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org
```

This will automatically perform geo-location to give you a nearby server (reducing the latency error) and Ubuntu will adjust for your timezone (so if the server is in a different timezone, it's still all okay). Alternatively, you can use `ntp.ubuntu.com`.

Note that if you're very unlucky, none of the time servers you're using will handle the leap second correctly. It's unlikely, but possible. Checking manually against a known good source (analogue radio, possibly [time.is](https://time.is)) is advised.

---

Alternatively, if you're on a modern version of Ubuntu, there's a built in utility called `timedatectl`. By default, this runs once automatically on startup. Therefore, a quick reboot can force a sync if necessary.

Comment: In the U.K., using time.nist.gov still works. Ubuntu adjusts what it reports for my timezone. I assume the same is true for all time zones

Comment: @Tim Yes, but synching with a server in the US has higher latency = higher error rate... so it works, but the end result is less precise than with using a closer server.

Comment: Try `pool.ntp.org` instead; this should always pick up something relatively close to you.

Comment: This answer is problematic. 1.) If you're very unlucky, none of the time servers you'll using will handle the leap second correctly. It's unlikely, but possible. 2.) If `ntpd` is running, running `ntpdate` simultaneously will confuse it. Better to stop it first. Better yet, don't run `ntpdate` at all. 3.) The NIST time servers don't need extra traffic from Stack Exchange; `ntp.ubuntu.com` or `pool.ntp.org` would be better. 4.) The UK actually uses `uk.pool.ntp.org`, but `pool.ntp.org` will perform geolocation anyway.

Comment: I forgot one. 5.) If you're running `ntpdate` against random time servers, and you're very unlucky again, you'll use one that also failed to handle the leap second correctly! The NTP Pool deactivates such servers quickly, but not instantly. And prominent government servers aren't any better. (Though i think the NIST ones were this time.)

Answer (score 17):

Leap seconds are handled automatically by the Linux kernel, no reboot or NTP sync is required to keep actual time. If you look in your system log, you will see something similar to

```
[263284.397894] Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC
```

Since `23:59:60` is not a valid Linux time, your clock will reach `00:00:00`, then step back to `23:59:59`. Any objects created during that second (like files) can be dated inconsistently.

As far as Linux time (as opposed to real time) is concerned, leap seconds don't exist:

```
# date -d "2016-12-31 23:59:59" +%s
1483225199
# date -d "2017-01-01 00:00:00" +%s
1483225200
```

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep leap` has no output on either my local machine or VPS. Local machine was off at local midnight, probably off at UTC midnight, and VPS was on entire time. Both are 16.04. Any idea why?

Comment: My logs do appear to confirm this answer. I recently ran `dmesg | grep 'leap second'` on my main 16.04 machine and it showed `[1153894.866672] Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC`. This, just with different numbers at the beginning, was also shown on my minimal 16.04 VM, installed from `mini.iso`, that I use for testing. That minimal system does not have `ntpd` running, nor does it have [either of the `ntp` or `openntpd` packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ntpd&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) installed.

Comment: I have checked both `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg`, and there is no mention of anything like this.

Comment: @EliahKagan Surely the kernel does not have a list of all future leap seconds hardcoded. The kernel has the logic to insert the leap second, but something must tell the kernel that a leap second is to be inserted. I don't know of anything other than NTP which can tell the kernel to insert a leap second. Notice that if the kernel has already been instructed to insert a leap second, then uninstalling NTP without rebooting will leave the kernel in a state where it will insert a leap second.

Comment: @kasperd Yep, no software can have a hardcoded list of leap seconds which can't be scheduled far into the future.

Comment: @kasperd I agree with your general reasoning, but I don't think NTP has ever been installed in that system, which I set up just a few (though more than one) days earlier. Two possibilities come to my mind. This is a VMware virtual machine, and though I haven't installed any VMware drivers, I believe Ubuntu already has some. Might such a driver have found out about the leap second from the host machine? Aside from that, I expect NTP was involved during installation, though I'm not sure how that was made to work across reboots. I think `mini.iso` itself has NTP and that debian-installer uses it.

Comment: @EliahKagan Good question. I don't know the answer. I believe a VM can get more accurate time keeping with lower overhead if only the host runs NTP and the VM has access to query the time of the host system. I don't know whether such a thing has been implemented, but it certainly is a possibility.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I did not check, but the default ntp client may be `chrony`.

Comment: It depends on the configuration of the NTP client whether leap seconds are handled as such or if the clock is simply slowed down. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/06/01/five-different-ways-handle-leap-seconds-ntp/

Comment: @CarstenS It turns out [systemd-timesyncd(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/systemd-timesyncd.8.html) has been synchronizing my minimal system's clock. I hadn't thought of this, and found out by semi-accident: `grep -RPis '(?<!mou)ntp' /var/log` revealed [these 14 syslog lines](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23728105/), showing time syncs from a host that happens to have `ntp` in its name. In hindsight, it makes sense that the mysterious service I never knew I had was part of systemd. (Btw, good point about chrony, which I hadn't checked for either; it's not installed, though.)

Comment: Although I believe that the additional leap second was incremented, I never found anything as is described in the answer in my logs. So not sure about this.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda maybe your system is configured to use clock slew rather than step (`ntp -x` or `leapsecmode=slew` in `chrony`)? I'm not sure which messages (if any) appear in the log in the clock slew case.